# Add Logo Upload per Setting API

Tags: settings-api

I have created a section field like this →

```
    // Logo Upload Option
add_settings_field(
    'logo_upload',                              // The ID (or the name) of the field
    'Upload the Header Logo',                   // The text used to label the field
    'upload_logo_field',                // The callback function used to render the field
    'theme-header-options',             // The page on which we'll be rendering this field
    'header_section'                            // The section to which we're adding the setting
);
```

Then created the callback function like this →

```
function upload_logo_field() {
    ?>
        <input type="file" name="logo" />
        <?php echo get_option('logo'); ?>
    <?php
```

Now I have created a Video [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/cNakFh1t2). It looks like that things are working, but actually I believe that I am still missing something?

I think it is still not saving into the database? I believe I need to add something else? Do I need to to create `register_setting` for every field or `register_setting` is for some sections only and should be done once for every section or register_setting is needed to be done for every `add_setting_field`?

Comment: I believe I am still not able to save it into the database, and I will be needing a function to do that, but where can I add that extra call back function? and what will I write in that extra call back function?

Comment: In short what I am missing is saving this into the database.